# Clojure: Lein figwheel and ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to run lein figwheel on a ClojureScript app and I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, compiling:(cljs/closure.clj:1:1)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)    at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)  at
>   clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)     at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)     at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)   at
>   clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)  at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)     at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)    at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)    at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:3204)  at
>   cljs.repl$eval10915$loading__5569__auto____10916.invoke(repl.cljc:9)
>     at cljs.repl$eval10915.invokeStatic(repl.cljc:9)    at
>   cljs.repl$eval10915.invoke(repl.cljc:9)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)    at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)  at
>   clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)     at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)     at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)   at
>   clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)  at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)     at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)    at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)    at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1523)  at
>   figwheel_sidecar.repl$eval10909$loading__5569__auto____10910.invoke(repl.clj:1)
>     at figwheel_sidecar.repl$eval10909.invokeStatic(repl.clj:1)     at
>   figwheel_sidecar.repl$eval10909.invoke(repl.clj:1)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)    at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)  at
>   clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)     at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)     at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)   at
>   clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)  at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)     at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)    at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)    at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1523)  at
>   figwheel_sidecar.system$eval10903$loading__5569__auto____10904.invoke(system.clj:1)
>     at figwheel_sidecar.system$eval10903.invokeStatic(system.clj:1)     at
>   figwheel_sidecar.system$eval10903.invoke(system.clj:1)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)    at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)  at
>   clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)     at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)     at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)   at
>   clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)  at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)     at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)    at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)    at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:930)   at
>   figwheel_sidecar.repl_api$eval9$loading__5569__auto____10.invoke(repl_api.clj:1)
>     at figwheel_sidecar.repl_api$eval9.invokeStatic(repl_api.clj:1)     at
>   figwheel_sidecar.repl_api$eval9.invoke(repl_api.clj:1)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)    at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)   at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)  at
>   clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)     at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)     at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)   at
>   clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)  at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)     at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)    at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)    at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)  at
>   clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)     at
>   clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init1038311299988387512.clj:1)   at
>   user$eval5.invoke(form-init1038311299988387512.clj:1)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)    at
>   clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)   at
>   clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)  at
>   clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)    at
>   clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)    at
>   clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)  at
>   clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)    at
>   clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)  at
>   clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)   at
>   clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)     at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)  at
>   clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)    at
>   clojure.main.main(main.java:37) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter    at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
>     at
>   clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:69)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>     at
>   clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:77)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2168)    at
>   clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(RT.java:2181)  at
>   cljs.closure$eval12201$loading__5569__auto____12202.invoke(closure.clj:9)
>     at cljs.closure$eval12201.invokeStatic(closure.clj:9)   at
>   cljs.closure$eval12201.invoke(closure.clj:9)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)    ... 153 more

I've checked my dev environment and confirmed I'm running Java 11 and that I have the latest version of lein. The little info I can find online is that this was a Java 9 issue, but there's nothing else past that. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

I only add `[javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.3.0"]` into my `:dependencies` of the `project.clj` according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53039959/5022162this post, then it would be worked well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a few months ago.  Do a `lein deps :tree`. One of your dependencies is using an outdated lib.  You should also be using [the lein-ancient plugin](https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient) to make sure all of your direct dependencies are up-to-date.

Once you upgrade all your libs, the problem should go away.  If it is a 3rd level dep including an outdated lib, put that lib (with newest version) at the top of your lein `:dependencies` (lein follows the rule "first one wins" when multiple deps versions are present).

---

***In addition***, you should consider upgrading to Figwheel-Main.  It is ***much*** easier to use than the original figwheel.  It also allows you to use the Clojure Deps build system instead of `lein`, which will also greatly simplify your CLJS development.

Answer (score 2):

After the modularization of JDK released with Java 9 certain parts of it are no longer available within the standard bundle.
This is the case of `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` which resides in the `java.xml.bind` module.

It might be that it's just a simple upgrade to the latest libs/tools you use but in case you actually need that dependency you should specify it as a `java` arg: `--add-modules java.xml.bind` (see [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) for more deteails).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ran `lein ancient` (without making changes), then did `lein figwheel` and suddenly it worked?!? Not sure what made the difference.